# How to remove certain words from suggestions?

Tags: languagetool

I'm running my own instance of https://languagetool.org/ and I don't know how to remove certain words from the suggestions. There's a latin word 'sunt', which when checked by the tool returns a similar word where s is replaced with c, followed by 'unt'. I want to take this word out of the suggested words. I've tried adding it to the multiple files inside '/org/languagetool/resource/en/hunspell' but I haven't had any luck. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Cheers,

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the word you want to avoid to `org/languagetool/resource/en/hunspell/prohibit.txt`. I cannot reproduce the problem, by the way. Are you sure you're using a recent version of LanguageTool?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I was running an old version which had word cnut in it. I think it was version 4.2. Upgraded the LanguageTool and the suggestion isn't there any longer. I had two versions running and was making changes to the wrong one which is why I couldn't see the changes.